# Pandas reading tall data into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which consists of tall data. I want to iterate through each line within the text file and create a Dataframe.

The text file looks like this, note that the same fields don't exist for all Users (e.g some might have an email field some might not), Also note that each User is separated by[User]:

```
[User]
Field=Data
employeeNo=123
last_name=Toole
first_name=Michael
language=english
department=Marketing
role=Marketing Lead
[User]
employeeNo=456
last_name= Ronaldo
first_name=Juan
language=Spanish
email=juan.ronaldo@sms.ie
department=Data Science
role=Team Lead
Location=Spain
[User]
employeeNo=998
last_name=Lee
first_name=Damian
language=english
email=damian.lee@email.com
[User]
```

My issue is as follows:
My code iterates through the data but for any field that is not present for that User it iterates down through the list and takes the next piece of data relating to that field.

**For example** Look at the output below (click on the link below) the first User does not have an email associated with him so the code assigns the email of the second user in the list, however what I want to do is return Nan/N/A/blank if no information is available

[Click here to view DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcpnr.png)

```
## Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame



## Import Data
## Set column names so that no lines in the text file are missed"
col_names = ['Field',
             'Data']


## If you have been sent this script you need to change the file path below, change it to where you have the .txt file saved
textFile = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\SampleData.txt', delimiter="=", engine='python', names=col_names)


## Get a list of the unique IDs  
new_cols = pd.unique(textFile['Field'])
userListing_DF = pd.DataFrame()

## Create a for loop to iterate through the first column and get the unique columns, then concatenate those unique values with data
for col in new_cols:
    tmp = textFile[textFile['Field'] == col]
    tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)
    userListing_DF = pd.concat([userListing_DF, tmp['Data']], axis=1)
    
userListing_DF.columns = new_cols
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in the single long column, and then form a group indicator by seeing where the value is '[User]'. Then separate the column labels and values, with a `str.split` and join back to your DataFrame. Finally pivot to your desired shape.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\n', header=None)

df['Group'] = df[0].eq('[User]').cumsum()
df = df[df[0].ne('[User]')]  # No longer need these rows

df = pd.concat([df, df[0].str.split('=', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'col', 1: 'val'})],
               axis=1)

df = df.pivot(index='Group', columns='col', values='val').rename_axis(columns=None)
```

---

```
      Field Location    department                 email employeeNo first_name language last_name            role
Group                                                                                                            
1      Data      NaN     Marketing                   NaN        123    Michael  english     Toole  Marketing Lead
2       NaN    Spain  Data Science   juan.ronaldo@sms.ie        456       Juan  Spanish   Ronaldo       Team Lead
3       NaN      NaN           NaN  damian.lee@email.com        998     Damian  english       Lee             NaN
```